# Pip in venv does not consider installed packages

Tags: pip, pypi, python-venv, python-packaging

I have created a Python package that I want to install with pip in my venv.
It has several dependencies. These are not all on pypi but they are also existing locally.

If I do

```bash
python -m venv /.../venv/
source /.../venv/bin/activate
pip list
```

i get

```bash
Package             Version Editable project location
------------------- ------- --------------------------------------------
dune-alugrid        2.9.0   /dune/dune-alugrid/build-cmake/python
dune-common         2.9.0   /dune/dune-common/build-cmake/python
dune-foamgrid       2.10.0  /dune/dune-foamgrid/build-cmake/python
dune-functions      2.9.0   /dune/dune-functions/build-cmake/python
dune-geometry       2.9.0   /dune/dune-geometry/build-cmake/python
dune-grid           2.9.0   /dune/dune-grid/build-cmake/python
dune-istl           2.9.0   /dune/dune-istl/build-cmake/python
dune-localfunctions 2.9.0   /dune/dune-localfunctions/build-cmake/python
dune-vtk            2.9.0   /dune/dune-vtk/build-cmake/python
Jinja2              3.1.2
MarkupSafe          2.1.2
mpi4py              3.1.4
ninja               1.11.1
numpy               1.24.2
pip                 23.0.1
portalocker         2.7.0
scipy               1.10.1
setuptools          67.4.0
wheel               0.38.4
```

Now I want to install now my package with

`pip install pyikarus --verbose` or with `python -m pip install pyikarus --verbose`( The output is the same).

`pip`does not recognize the installed packages with `dune-*`.
Hence, pip starts to download the ones that exists at pypi.
Therefore, it starts with lines like

```py
  Collecting dune-common<=2.9.0
    Downloading dune-common-2.9.0.tar.gz (823 kB)
       ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 824.0/824.0 kB 7.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Collecting dune-grid<=2.9.0
    Downloading dune-grid-2.9.0.tar.gz (3.0 MB)
       ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.0/3.0 MB 5.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
    Installing build dependencies: started
```

But it fails with

```py
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dune-functions<=2.9.0 (from versions: none)
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for dune-functions<=2.9.0
```

because `dune-functions` does not exists at pypi.

***Question***
What is wrong with my installation process, and why does pip not consider these installed packages for my module?
Or can someone give me a hint how to debug this myself?

For completeness in my `setup.py` file I have as deps written:

```yaml
requires = ['setuptools', 'wheel', 'scikit-build', 'cmake', 'ninja', 'requests', 'dune-common<=2.9.0', 'dune-grid<=2.9.0', 'dune-geometry<=2.9.0', 'dune-localfunctions<=2.9.0', 'dune-functions<=2.9.0', 'dune-istl<=2.9.0']
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stipulated, your `install_requires` specifies that you want to install `"dune-functions<=2.9.0"`:

```py
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        'setuptools', 
        ...,
        'dune-common<=2.9.0',
        'dune-grid<=2.9.0',
        'dune-geometry<=2.9.0',
        'dune-localfunctions<=2.9.0',
        'dune-functions<=2.9.0',
        'dune-istl<=2.9.0'
    ]
    ...
)
```

However, you never stipulate here that `dune-functions` package has to be found locally (or any dune-* package either). So `pip` looks for them on pypi and.. does not find `dune-functions` since it is not on pypi.

---

There are several different solutions to solve this problem.

The first (and most ugly one):

```py
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        'setuptools', 
        ...,
        '/path/to/dune-common/setup_py/location/',
        '/path/to/dune-grid/setup_py/location/',
        '/path/to/dune-geometry/setup_py/location/',
        '/path/to/dune-localfunctions/setup_py/location/',
        '/path/to/dune-functions/setup_py/location/',
        '/path/to/dune-istl/setup_py/location/',
    ]
    ...
)
```

This can be considered dirty since the `/path/to/dune-*` folders won't necessarily exist on another machine installing your package.

---

Another solution would be to create your own pypi server. For example, [`devpi`](https://github.com/devpi/devpi) is a common tool for this purpose. Using devpi, you could create a server, host your own packages, mirror the rest of pypi and simply do:

```bash
pip install pyikarus -i https://yourowndevpiserver.com
```